# How to apply .ttc to a Font in Java awt

Tags: java, fonts, awt, inputstream, embedded-resource

I was trying to read a .ttc file using java.io.InputStream in IntelliJ IDEA, but it failed.

Here is my code:

```java
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Dependencies\\msjh.ttc");
Font font;
try
{
    if (inputStream == null)
        throw new IOException();
    font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, inputStream).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN);
}
catch (IOException | FontFormatException exception)
{
    font = new Font("Microsoft JhengHei UI", Font.PLAIN, 16);
}
```

No matter how I try, the condition `if (inputStream == null)` is always true and the IOException will be thrown.

But a similar way of setting window icon works:

```java
Frame frame = new Frame("Window");
frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Dependencies\\icon.png"));
```

Here are paths from my files :

```
IdeaProjects\Project\Dependencies\msjh.ttc (font file)
IdeaProjects\Project\Dependencies\icon.png (image file)
IdeaProjects\Project\src\bin_gen\Main.java (source code)
```

and there is a VM option: `-Dfile.encoding=MS950`

That .ttc file was copied from `C:\Windows\Fonts\Microsoft JhengHei UI`. I'm trying this because `font = new Font("Microsoft JhengHei UI", Font.PLAIN, 16);` seems not working (The font display on the window is still the default font).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `getResource` rather than `getResourceAsStream`. They follow slightly different rules and I understand the rules of the former well.

**If** the font is in the Jar created by the IDE, it will be located at `/Dependencies/msjh.ttc`.

Note the two separate forward slashes (`/`) as opposed to a file-like back-slash (`\\`). That backslash is only for files, and only on Windows. What `getResource` needs is a resource path either direct from the project or jar root, or relative to the class calling it. The `/` prefix tells the JRE to look for the resource from the root of the classpath, rather than relative to the calling class.

Also don't use `getImage("Dependencies\\icon.png")`. That will presume the string represents a file path, which won't work when the project is deployed. Use `getResource` for that as well.